# PHP - preg_match() and eregi() not working?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to validate email adresses using preg_match (or eregi() if that suits better). I've tried several regex patterns now and no matter what i do it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the function:

```
function validateEmail($email) {

    if(eregi('[a-z||0-9]@[a-z||0-9].[a-z]', $email)){
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any ideas what's wrong? I've tried putting an exclamation point before the eregi (and preg_match that i used before), and that reversed it all (as expected) but still didn't make it work as it should. I want it to return TRUE if it does not pass the regex.

And i didn't use the same regex when on the preg_match function, i found another one then, cause i know you can't really mix those two. Right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not a proper regular expression. `[<something>]` does only match one character, and `.` is treated as a special character matching *any* character, not only `.`. A more correct regex could be: `[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,4}`, although this is - as nikic said - too strict too.

Comment: Your regex doesn't work either, so i don't think it's the regex that's messing this up.

Answer (score 8):

You ought to use the filter extension through [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

If you want a regex, don't use a strict rule, or my `+@example.org` domain will be rejected. Use something like `~[^@]+@(?:[^.]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}~`. Though this will still not allow valid emails like `"\@"@example.org`.

PS: If you want to know why your regex doesn't work:

- eregi is deprecated, use preg_match instead
- inside `[]` don't write `||`. Simply use `[a-z0-9]`. `||` would simply additionally allow the `|` character
- You forgot the `+` quantifiers everywhere. Right know every part may have only one character.

With all those things fixed (but please don't use this regex!):

```
preg_match('~[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+.[a-z]+~i', $email);
```

Comment: I didn't even know that existed, but it sounds good. It still doesn't work for some reason though.

Comment: It returns false no matter what i input. I can leave it blank and submit the form, but it still returns false. Same thing if i enter a valid email. And if i put an exclamation point before the preg_match, it inverses the action and returns true no matter what you submit.

Comment: That's it? Nothing else to contribute with?

Comment: Could you please provide us this the function code you are currently using? It should be `function validateEmail($email) { return (bool) filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); }`.

Comment: I finally got it working as i wanted it to. To be honest i'm not sure what was wrong before, but after playing with it for over an hour i somehow managed to get it working as it should. I used filter_var as you suggested, and it seems cool. Why are everybody suggesting regex when there already is a built-in function that validates email adresses? Oh well, thanks once again, and here's the code:  function validateEmail($email) {  
  if( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
   return true;
  }
 }

Comment: People simply dont know about filters, that's all ;)

Comment: Well, the filter_var function isn't around all that long, since PHP 5.2.0, when I started with PHP version 4 was just brand new...

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify some stuff, `ereg` is depreciated.

To convert that to `preg_match` it would be:

```
if(preg_match('/[a-z||0-9]@[a-z||0-9].[a-z]/', $email)){
```

Most  (I use this term loosely) `ereg`'s just need delimiters (the first and last / ) added to be converted to `preg_match`.